# Linux: remove file extensions for multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have many files with .txt extension.
How to remove .txt extension for multiple files in linux?

I found that

```
rename .old .new *.old
```

substitutes `.old` extension to the `.new`

Also I want to do this for files in sub-folders.

Comment: I think the title should be: Linux: rename file extensions for multiple files

Comment: Yep, this definitely lead me here by mistake, this question is about changing the extension not removing it

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`rename` is slightly dangerous, since according to its [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html):

> rename will rename the specified files by replacing the **first** occurrence of...

It will happily do the wrong thing with filenames like `c.txt.parser.y`.

Here's a solution using `find` and `bash`:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done
```

Keep in mind that this will break if a filename contains a newline (rare, but not impossible).

If you have GNU find, this is a more solid solution:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done
```

Comment: That's true regarding the `util-linux-ng` version of `rename`, but the Perl script version can do `rename 's/.txt$//' *.txt`

Comment: you are missing current "." as for the location where you want to run in. maybe this is my osx variant of find, or my path is not set correctly

Comment: @bgs: most (all?) Linux distributions use GNU find, which defaults to . when no argument has been specified

Comment: yes, don't forget the directory specifier if you are on Mac. e.g. `find . -type f -name '*.txt' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done`

Comment: Why is the second one more solid than the first one?

Answer (score 25):

I use this:

```
find ./ -name "*.old" -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `basename "$0" .old`.new' '{}' \;
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't know this syntax, and it works also on MacOSX (which lacks native `rename` ).

Comment: You should have added the dirname in case target is in a subfolder :

    find ./ -name "*.old" -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `dirname "$0"`/`basename "$0" .old`.new' '{}' \;

Answer (score 17):

The Perl version of rename can remove an extension as follows:

```
rename 's/\.txt$//' *.txt
```

This could be combined with find in order to also do sub-folders.

Answer (score 10):

You can explicitly pass in an empty string as an argument.

`rename .old '' *.old`

And with subfolders, `find . -type d -exec rename .old '' {}/*.old \;`.  `{}` is the substitute for the entry found with `find`, and `\;` terminates the arglist for the command given after `-exec`.

Comment: I don't know what version of `rename` you used there, but it doesn't work here on the Debian version, which is a perl script that uses regex for the arguments. This works: `$ rename 's/\.old//' *.old`

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps, here's how I do it with zsh:

```
for f in ./**/*.old; do
    mv "${f}" "${f%.old}"
done
```

The `${x%pattern}` construct in zsh removes the shortest occurence of `pattern` at the end of `$x`. Here it is abstracted as a function:

```
function chgext () {
    local srcext=".old"
    local dstext=""
    local dir="."

    [[ "$#" -ge 1 ]] && srcext="$1"
    [[ "$#" -gt 2 ]] && dstext="$2" dir="$3" || dir="${2:-.}"

    local bname=''
    for f in "${dir}"/**/*"${srcext}"; do
        bname="${f%${srcext}}"
        echo "${bname}{${srcext} → ${dstext}}"
        mv "${f}" "${bname}${dstext}"
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
chgext
chgext src
chgext src dir
chgext src dst dir

Where `src` is the extension to find (default: ".old")
      `dst` is the extension to replace with (default: "")
      `dir` is the directory to act on (default: ".")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Fish, you can do

```
for file in *.old
      touch (basename "$file" .old).new
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For subfolders:

```
for i in `find myfolder -type d`; do
  rename .old .new $i/*.old
done
```

Comment: This can cause problems if there's a folder name with a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

execute in bash linux

```
for i in *;do mv ${i} ${i/%.pdf/} ;done
```