# how to delete filename's specific suffix in a dir, in linux

Tags: linux, shell, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)
>   [Linux: remove file extensions for multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509485/linux-remove-file-extensions-for-multiple-files)

```
For example, A.txt B.txt, I want to rename then to A and B .
```

How can I do it with shell script?  Or other method ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.txt
do
    echo "$file" "$( echo $file | sed -e 's/\.txt//' )"
done
```

Of course replace the two above references of ".txt" to whatever file extension you are removing, or, preferably just use $1 (the first passed argument to the script).

Michael G.

Comment: `$(ls *.txt)` should just be `*.txt`, `$file` should be quoted as `"$file"` (as well as the `"$( echo ... )"`), and the regexp should be `'s/\.txt$//'` (the `g` flag means "do multiple substitutions", which is not what you want, you only want one).

Comment: Thank you, I will change the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "${i%.txt}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for FILE in *.txt ; do mv -i "$FILE" "$(basename "$FILE" .txt)" ; done
```