# What is the meaning of the "\e" in the example in the man page of rename?

Tags: regex, linux, rename

This is a quote from the `rename` man page:

> ```
>    For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the
>    extension, you might say
>
>          rename 's/\e.bak$//' *.bak
> ```

Why is there a `\e`?

The command doesn't seem to work, whereas the simpler command `rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak` does the job. Could it be a mistake in the documentation ?

Comment: I don't see any `\e`: http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/rename/

Comment: You're right. It appears to be on the 1P (POSIX) man page only: http://man.foreach.site/en/1p/file-rename

Comment: Is this the Perl version of rename? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509485/linux-remove-file-extensions-for-multiple-files

Comment: Probably. The doc mentions perl quite a few times.

Comment: It's not only on the 1P page: http://man.foreach.site/en/1/rename
I see it on the "updated 2014-05-05" version of man page, but not on the older "2011-08-10" version.

My Debian 8 Jessie distribution has the `\e` in the man page.