# copy file n times and rename it with specific names

Tags: bash, copy, rename

Let's suppose I have a bash script named `bash.sh` in a folder `/home/test/` and within this folder I also have 5 more files named as: `file_1a.nc file_1b.nc file_2a.nc file_6a.nc file_6b.nc`.

I would like to copy `bash.sh` 5 times and the new copies need to have the same name as the .nc files, as follows:

`file_1a_bash.sh file_1b_bash.sh file_2a_bash.sh file_6a_bash.sh file_6b_bash.sh`

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simple case of [`bash` Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) processing.

```
for f in file_*.nc; do cp bash.sh "${f%.nc}_bash.sh"; done
```

Comment: The idea seems good to me, but [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies missing quotes in the code.

Comment: @pjh missing quotes wouldn't be a problem in this particular case since samples in the OP do not contain spaces or any other meta-chars. Please don't make shellcheck another cargo cult

Comment: It is nonetheless a good habit to always put quotes unless there is a sound and explicit reason not to do so. I just wanted to keep the example minimal and simplistic to accentuate the point, but now that's been done, I'll add them as good form.

Answer (score -2):

You can apply this earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509485/linux-remove-file-extensions-for-multiple-files) to your case

```
find /home/test/ -type f -name '*.nc' | while read f; do 
mv "$f" "${f%.nc}_bash.sh";
```

You can also use `ls -1` when you are in `/home/test/` instead of `find`;

```
for f in `ls -1 file_*` ; do 
cp ${f} "${f%.nc}"_bash.sh; 
done
```

Comment: I would do for f in file_* ; do  cp "${f}" "${f%.nc}"_bash.sh; done
It's not convenient to use ls to loop files, use glob notation instead. And always protect your vars double quoting them. You can have a check on https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Neither find nor ls is required here