# Bash renaming with For Loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have files name filename.gz.1 and i need to rename them to filename.gz,
There are allot of files and every name is different,

I know i cant to this `for i in $(ls); do mv $i $i.1; done`,
But can i do this reverse, from filename.gz.1 to filename.gz and keep the original file name?

I have tried this,

```
for i in $(ls | grep "xz\|gz"); do echo "mv $i $i | $(rev) | $(cut -c3-) | $(rev) |)"; done
```

But this ignores my Pipes.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you see [Linux: remove file extensions for multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4509485/3266847)?

Comment: Btw.: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: If all files have extra ".1" you can just cut this one. If you have ".2" ".11" it will require a bit more conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
for i in ...;
do
    echo "$i --> ${i%.*}"
done
```

The `${i%.*}` will remove at the end (`%`)  what match a period followed by anything (`.*`)

Comment: file.gz will be renamed to file, so it is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `--extended-regexp` when using a pipe as separation.

```
echo -e "foo.xz\nbar.gz\nbaz" | grep -E "(xz|gz)"
```

and don't use `ls` for list your files, it is not save. instead you can use a loop to search for files.

```
for file in /PATH/TO/FILES; do
echo $file
done
```

I would also recommend to use regex to search for filenames ending with a number, like ...

```
if [[ $file =~ [[:digit:]]$ ]]; then
  echo ${file%.*}
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve it like this:

```
for i in $(ls | grep "xz\|gz"); do echo "mv $i $i" | rev | cut -c3- | rev; done | bash
```